# how to use composite from imagemagick in drupal custom image style

Tags: drupal, imagemagick

Here is my goal:
after the scale_and_crop effect has been applied, iu want to create a sprite that will hold the cropped image + a copy of it beneath that will have an effect applied to it (known as compose multiply).
I am able to generate the "effected" image in the command line using images like this:

```
       $cmd = 'composite -compose Multiply -gravity center \
        ' . $img_original_path . ' ' . $img_texture_path . ' ' .$img_result_destination;

    $return = null;
    $output = array();
    exec($cmd, $output, $return);
    var_dump($cmd, $output, $return);
```

My last resort will be to wrap the call to the style in the template to generate the sprite when it is called from the cropped image, but i would love to be able to do it in one pass...

And thanks for the time you spent reading !

Comment: your question is a little hard to understand. Have you tried the imagecache actions module? http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions

Comment: hi ! yes, though, my problem relies more in the fact that i am trying to render several images and combine them into one sprite, using the drupal hooks (havent found any modules doing this).

Comment: hmm, I know that the imagecache actions can apply an overlay, but multiple images maybe not

Comment: you may have to create your own module using the GD php library

Comment: yes, that is what i have been doing, i may very well end up creating a module to handle the effect (this special image transformation) is not given out of the box by the various modules, and use another style for the crop only, so i will end up with 2 images... but i guess i will live with that.

Comment: There is also the imagecache_actions module. I didn't realize they had ported this to drupal 7. http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions